# Post and redirect to different pages - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following form:

```
<form name="my_form" action="http://localhost:3000/foo" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="username">
</form>
```

Now I want to post that form to page `foo` and redirect to page `bar`:

```
window.onload = function() {
     setTimeout( function() { 
        var myform = document.forms['my_form'];
        myform.onsubmit = function() { 
                setTimeout(function() {  
                    window.top.location = "http://localhost:3000/bar"
                }, 10); 
        }
        myform.submit();
    }, 10);
}
```

However I continue to be redirected to the page `foo` regardless ... any clues?

Comment: So you want to post information to `foo` but redirect the user to `bar` ?

Comment: Have you thought about using ajax? then you can redirect if the call is successful?

Comment: @NewToJS Can't use ajax unfortunately ...

Comment: Okay, i'm not sure why you wouldn't be able to use it. What sort of page is this `foo` you want to send data to? Does it return anything after the data is sent? I'm not sure why `XMLHttpRequest()` wouldn't be possible.